# ¿Cómo cambiar de color a una View dinámica en Android?

Tags: android, views

Estoy haciendo unos botones dinámicos en *Android*. La creación funciona muy bien, el problema viene cuando quiero cambiar el color de fondo del botón seleccionado.

Al inicio de mi codigo, el botón en la primera posición esta marcado en rojo. Ahora, ¿Cómo haría para que al seleccionar el botón en la posición 2, el botón antes seleccionado pase a negro y el actual pase a rojo?

Código *XML*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#000000"
        >    
        </LinearLayout>    
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Código *Java*:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

final ArrayList<String> arg = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    arg.add("hola" + i);

    final RelativeLayout rltv = new RelativeLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500);

    rltv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    final TextView tvt = new TextView(this);
    tvt.setText(arg.get(i).toString());

    int paddingPixel = 25;
    float density = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int paddingDp = (int) (paddingPixel * density);
    tvt.setPadding(paddingDp, paddingDp, 0, 0);
    tvt.setTextSize(25);
    tvt.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    rltv.addView(tvt);

    LinearLayout relativeLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutParams.setMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);

    relativeLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
    rltv.setTag(i);
    relativeLayout1.addView(rltv);
    layout.addView(relativeLayout1, layoutParams);

    if (rltv.getTag().equals(0)) {
        rltv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rojoOpciones));
    } else {
        rltv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.negro));
    }
    rltv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Listener botón 1 " + v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            opcion = (int) v.getTag();
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rojoOpciones));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Cuales son tus dos botones? solo veo al parecer el `rltv`

Comment: sioesi por cada iteracion del ciclo for agrego una view al rltv y a su vez cada una de esas views trabaja como un boton, con su evento de onClick independiente. Como dije arriba el codigo funciona solo que no logro hacer el cambio de colores de fondos entre las views.

Comment: quieres que el botón seleccionado sea rojo?

Comment: @Jorgesys si el que seleccione quede en rojo y el que estaba seleccionado previamente pase a negro en el fondo. Lo estoy haciendo para un menú dinámico. Ya me funciona casi todo a excepción de esta parte del cambio de color de fondo.

Comment: @simaski más tarde me conecto, pero para realizar esto tienes que barrer todos los demás controles para cambiar su color a negro, en el sitio se tiene una pregunta algo similar creando vistas y cambiando su color.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya lo resolví. Mas tarde edito la pregunta y coloco la solución. Ahorita ando en el trabajo y no tengo tiempo para hacerlo. Igual gracias.